# How to make the header row be skipped in my while loop using fgetcsv?

Tags: php, file, csv, fgetcsv

I can't get the new code I've written to skip the first row (header) as the code I was using before did (see bottom).

I'm not receiving any errors, but just can't get it to omit first row.

```
$file = fopen($uploadcsv,"r");
$column_headers = array();
$row_count = 0;
while(!feof($file)) {   
  if ($row_count==0){
    $column_headers = $file;
  } else {
    print_r(fgetcsv($file));
  }
  ++$row_count;
  }

fclose($file);
```

Below is the old source that skipped the header, for reference and comparison.

```
$handle = fopen($uploadcsv, 'r');
$column_headers = array();
$row_count = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  if ($row_count==0){
    $column_headers = $data;
  } else {
    print_r($data);
  }
  ++$row_count;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why even count? Just get the headers before looping.

```
$column_headers = fgetcsv($file);
while(!feof($file)) {
   ...
```

Also, you're only assigning the file pointer to the variable.

Comment: please explain? so don't use $row_count==0? I'm going to need to assign it to $data for the array

Comment: What is this "$data" that you've decided to surprise us with?

Comment: oh i'm sorry, if you look at the coding up top (old coding) where I use $data for the array

Comment: @acctman: No you aren't. All I see there is some temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

When `$row_count` is `0` you are not **reading** any row.

Change

```
if ($row_count==0){
    $column_headers = $file;  // just assigning file handle.
}
```

to

```
if ($row_count==0){
    $column_headers = fgetcsv($file); // read the row.
}
```

Comment: how can i rewrite the column header detection the current way is giving a blank output