# Insert csv data into mysql according to headers

Tags: php, file, csv, fgetcsv

I have a simple scripts to upload csv file and it works .
But how if I want to handle the data with headers specified?
Such as if my table have 3 columns: FirstName,LastName,Address
and now my csv file is:

```
Address,FirstName,LastName
myadd,myfname,mylname
```

How to insert the data correctly into mysql according to the headers even it's not arrange same as table column name?

If I using my scripts , it will just insert myadd,myfname and mylname into FirstName,LastName and Address , even the headers will be inserted as well.

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<p>contents:</p>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}


$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="INSERT into CSVtest($column1,$column2,$column3,$column4,$column5) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);

Echo "Done";
```

}

Comment: Can you post your current script?

Comment: @Eric Thanks Eric,it's up there now.

Comment: This link may be what you are looking for since you are using fgetcsv

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409911/how-to-make-the-header-row-be-skipped-in-my-while-loop-using-fgetcsv

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the link,and now my header problem is solved , thanks Eric.

Comment: If you found a solution, you can post it below as an answer so the next person who finds this will have the solution too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have scripts : "If I using my scripts , it will just insert myadd,myfname and mylname into FirstName,LastName and Address , even the headers will be inserted as well."

I assume your scripts are generating the SQL to do this, namely you are saying INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(v1,v2,v3);

instead of doing it that way, do a named insert 
INSERT INTO user (f1,f2,f3) VALUES('v1','v2','v3');

in other words specify the field names in the script that generates the sql.